# How to use oAuth in a windows store app?

Tags: authentication, oauth, asp.net-web-api, windows-store-apps

I wonder how I can use external identity provider (*twitter, facebook, google,..*) to log in my application.

I have a **windows store app** and an **asp.net web Rest API** and the goal is to use an existing account (for example twitter) to provide to my Web Api an identity. So I can retrieve user's information and provide him the right one.

I don't understand the process and what I can use to do that. Some links have led me to *oAuth* but I don't see how to use it and I'm not sure it is the right way.

Is my Web API have to communicate with twitter or all information must be retrieved by the WS application and sent to the API?
How can I decode the retrieved information in my API?
What kind of information will I able to retrieve (an ID?)

Can somebody provide me some tutorial or example code to this kind of job?

EDIT: It seems I have to use Three-legged oAuth or the two-legged version of oAuth. I don't really understand which version I have to use. The 2-legged between Twitter and the store app or the 3-legged with twitter-WebApi-Windows store app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it is useful to give a complete description about the process since their is a lot of documentation already. But I can imagine it is easy to get lost, I can help you with a view pointers but it is easier to answer your questions when they become a bit more specific.

First off all with a OpenId provider the user has to Authorize your Api to use their information. This is where Oauth comes in place. You redirect your user to for example Google according to the Oauth2 protocol. The user will login with their google credentials and approve your app to use their information for an external id.

Second Twitter is still using the Oauth1 protocol and their have been some great improvements, especially in simplicity, in the Oauth2 protocol. So to start off I would start with Facebook/Google/Instagram (which has a very nice documentation) who support the Oauth2 protocol. Also have a look at this image:

[image: Oauth2 flow]

Too start with Oauth I would have a look at DotNetOpenAuth, this is a library that takes almost all of the complex logic away. They have some nice samples which you can download [here](https://github.com/DotNetOpenAuth/DotNetOpenAuth). I hope this helps you getting started.